# Adding an Attribute Route without parameters in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an API Controller Action defined as:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(string userId, string password)
```

My original plan was to pass both `userId` and `password` through the `data` attribute of an AJAX request instead of through the API url.

E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/users/resetpassword",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "userId" : userId,
        "password" : password
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    success: function () {
        $("#ResetPasswordModal").modal('toggle');
        toastr.success("Password Reset");
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#ResetPasswordModal").modal('toggle');
        toastr.error("Password could not be reset");
    }

});
```

However, if I apply the Attribute Route `[Route("api/users/resetpassword")]`

I get the error

> **No action was found on the controller 'Users' that matches the request**

If I *then* replace the attribute route with `[Route("api/users/{userId}/resetpassword/{password}")]`, the application is able to find the `ChangePassword` action successfully.

When applying Attribute Routes to Controller Actions, is it required that all attributes are included in the Route?

Comment: You are missing the HttpPost attribute and you should also make sure attribute routing is enables

Comment: You should also create a model to hold the data and use the FromBody attribute

Comment: Attribute routing is enabled and I receive the above error even with the HttpPost attribute applied to the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to hold the data sent from the client

```
public class ChangePasswordModel {
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

update the action to expect the data in the body of the request

```
public class UsersController: ApiController {

    //...

    //POST api/users/resetpassword
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/users/resetpassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody]ChangePasswordModel data) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

This assumes that attribute routing is already enabled in `WebApiConfig`.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And is based on the following client details

```
url: "/api/users/resetpassword",
data: JSON.stringify({
    "userId" : userId,
    "password" : password
}),
dataType: "json",
method: "POST",
```